# Concise way to check nested pointer struct for nil in Go?

Tags: json, pointers, go, struct, null

I have a nested struct coming from JSON. This struct has many optional properties and to successfully walk it, I need to check if properties exist. When properties are defined as pointer structs, it becomes very inconvenient: I have to instantiate an empty type and compare it using [reflect.DeepEqual](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).

Is there more concise way to do this?

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func unmarshalNested(data []byte) (nested, error) {
    var r nested
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &r)
    return r, err
}

type nested struct {
    Alfa alfa `json:"alfa"`
}

type alfa struct {
    Bravo *bravo `json:"bravo,omitempty"`
}

type bravo struct {
    Charlie string `json:"charlie"`
}

func main() {

    json := `
{
    "alfa": {
        "bravo": {
            "charlie": "foobar"
        }
    }
}
`
    /*
        json := "{"alfa": {}}
    */

    n := nested{}
    n, _ = unmarshalNested([]byte(json))

    fmt.Println("-- Alfa --")
    fmt.Printf("  %+v\n", n)

    fmt.Println("-- *Bravo --")

    var b *bravo = nil
    if reflect.DeepEqual(b, n.Alfa.Bravo) {
        fmt.Println("  nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("  %+v\n", n.Alfa.Bravo)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can compare pointers to `nil`, no need reflection. What is the question?

Comment: @icza You're right: `n.Alfa.Bravo == nil` works. I guess I overlooked that and tried to dereference it like this `*n.Alfa.Bravo == nil`. Would you mind posting this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare any pointer value to `nil`, no need reflection:

```
if n.Alpha.Bravo == nil {
    fmt.Println("  nil")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("  %+v\n", n.Alfa.Bravo)
}
```